# Sending SMS getting gateway timeout exception

Tags: java

I am using below code for sending SMS to user

```
URL url = new URL(urlToHit);
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

switch (connection.getResponseCode()) {
case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
    break;
case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT:
    break;
case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE:
    break;
default:
    LOGGER.error("Unknown response code");
}
```

Above code is working fine but sometimes it failed with `Gatewal Timeout Exception`

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: `URL`
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
```

Please suggest if I missed something in above code for sending SMS.

Comment: Try a different gateway.

Comment: Contact the people who run the gateway.  The behavior suggests that its is overloaded or unreliable.  Or maybe, you are sending SMS messages too often.